# Jquery Isotope: horizontally long images leaving gaps underneath

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I am using the [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin. I have a series of long (2x1), tall (1x2) and square (1x1) images. The design works ok as below:

[image]

But if the horizontal image appears in the first space, it mucks it all up:

[image]

Its like the plugin thinks all columns should be the width of whatever first image is supplied.

I have tried bodging it with some CSS:

```
.longimgholder {
height: 220px;
width: 220px;
overflow: visible;
z-index: 99;
}

.longimgholder img{
width: 420px;
}
```

But this doesnt work.

Would anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: set the column width to the smallest image width...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, its seems the first image that appears at the top left sets the width of the columns.

Its not a proper answer but I wrote a little script to skip the first image if it was a long image. This will ensure that the first image at the top left will always be a square or tall image.